# how to write query for this reuslt

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a employee table having column (**empno,enme,salary,deptno**)
I want to write a query which displays the following table:containing first column

- deptno

,second column

- sum of salaries of the employees of each department whose name start
  with 'A'

  and third column
- total slary of all the employees of that department

Any one please help me how to write query for this scenario..?

Comment: Don't you have any other tables?!? Check out `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: post some dummy data

Comment: Sounds a lot like homework

Comment: When you say in your second column "of each department" you want the total sum of all the salarys in all the department that starts with A or?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A have simulated your situation with a table variable and below is the result

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (empno int,ename VARCHAR(100),salary DECIMAL(18,2),deptno int)
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 1,'shuki',450,100
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 2,'arban',500,100
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 3,'alamet',300,200
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 4,'andrea',150,200
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 5,'florim',450,200

SELECT deptno,SUM(CASE when ename LIKE 'A%' THEN salary ELSE 0 END ) SalaryEmpWithA,SUM(salary) TotalSalary FROM @table
GROUP BY deptno
```

Output is:

```
deptno  SalaryEmpWithA  TotalSalary
100     500.00          950.00
200     450.00          900.00
```